# How to enact split on N element of zipped list

Tags: python, list, zip, list-comprehension

I have a zipped list, with each tuple originally having the same length that looks like this:

```
[('MATH 441', 'GREAT, LOTS OF HOMEWORK, FUNNY'),(CSCI 519, 'AWFUL, BORING')...]
```

My goal is to split the second element of the tuple into individual elements based on the comma. From here, each tuple may have different lengths, therefore, I would like to check if the given tuple meets a specific length, and if it does not, enter an 'NAN' element into the tuple.

I imagine we must create a "lists of list", for tuples are immutable so this is what I have created thus far.

```
master = list(zip(course_codez, lst))
#to make it a list of list, not a list of tuples
master_two = [list(a) for a in zip(course_codez, lst)]
for i in master_two:
    i[1].split(", ")
```

This is the thought process, but I am not entirely sure and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` doesn't (can't) modify the element in place, you need to assign the result back to the list element.

```
i[1] = i[1].split(", ")
```

You can do this directly in the list comprehension.

```
master_two = [(code, comment.split(", ")) for code, comment in zip(course_codez, lst)]
```

Comment: Hi barmar, thanks for the answer, it is very close to what I am looking for. This returns [('MATH 441, ['GREAT', 'LOTS OF HOMEWORK','FUNNY'])...]. Is there a way to perhaps have it has [['MATH 441', 'GREAT', LOTS OF HOMEWORK', 'FUNNY']].......]. Where each comment would be its own element with the sublist? I feel like this would make it easier in the long run for me so I can check the lengths of each sublist. Let me know what you think. Thanks again.

Comment: Why would that make it easier? A list should generally be homogeneous, why put the subject name in the same list as the comments?

Comment: You'll always have to remove the first element when you want to process just the comments.

Comment: But you could use `[code, *comments.split(", ")]` to spread the comments into the same list as the code.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Barmar! Im scraping a load of reviews, and would prefer to have it in a master list to input directly into relational database in one go. Its how i've done it in the past and have been successful. I am still a beginner in programing to be entirely honest.

Comment: Now I think you may not have normalized your relations properly. You shouldn't be putting the comments into multiple columns of the same row, you should have a separate row for each comment.